# Multiple conditions in conditional panel

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am creating a interactive shiny app and I am using multiple data tables. I want to plot histogram according to user's answer.First of all user selects a data table and then the below Select Box will change its content according to data table. But I'm not able to change the content and it keeps showing multiple Select Box for a single data table. Code:

```
 ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Data and their graphs"),
   tabsetPanel(
     tabPanel("Data",
              sidebarPanel(selectInput(inputId = "data1",label="Choose a dataset",choices=c("beaver1","esoph","iris"))),
              mainPanel(tableOutput(outputId = "table"))
              ),
     tabPanel("Histogram",
              sidebarPanel(selectInput(inputId = "data2",label="Choose a dataset",choices=c("beaver1","esoph","iris"))),
              conditionalPanel(condition="Input.data2=='beaver1' && Input.data2!='esoph' && Input.data2!='iris'",
                               selectInput("His",label="Select column",choices=c("time","temp","activ"))),
                               condition="Input.data2=='esoph'",
                               selectInput("His",label="Select column",choices=c("agegp","alcgp","tobgp","ncases","ncontrols")))




   )

)
```

Comment: In the `conditionalPanel` `condition`, try small 'i' in `Input.data2`: `input.data2`

Answer (score 0):

One can also use uiOutput().
It worked for me.